# How to add series values to date/datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'login_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','','10/11/1990'],
'DURATION':[21,30,200,34,45,np.NaN})
```

I would like to add `DURATION` values to the `login_date` column

The `DURATION` is represented in `Days` type

If there is `NA` in DURATION column, just replace it with 0.

So, I tried the below

```
df['DURATION'] = df['DURATION'].fillna(0)
df['login_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['login_date'])
df['DURATION'] = df['DURATION'].astype('Int64')
df['logout_Date'] = df['login_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=df['DURATION'])
```

However, this results in an error as shown below

```
TypeError: Invalid type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. Must be int or float.
```

But I have already converted my `DURATION` column to `int64` type.

How to add a column of values to my `logout_date` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["logout_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["login_date"]) + df["DURATION"].fillna(0).apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(days=x))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               login_date  DURATION         logout_date
0    5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM      21.0 2013-05-28 09:27:00
1  09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM      30.0 2013-10-08 11:21:00
2  06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM     200.0 2014-12-23 08:00:00
3  06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM      34.0 2014-07-10 05:00:00
4                              45.0                 NaT
5              10/11/1990       NaN 1990-10-11 00:00:00
```